# How to remove Live Chat powered by zendesk in my Joomla website?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla! 3.7.5 and template Helix3. I'd like to remove the Live Chat powered by zendesk. It is the blue help button. See picture.

[image]

When the buton is clicked, a live chat appear.

[image]

I've been looking everywhere in Joomla configuration, but seems cannot find the setting or page that I need to change. I look at the *index.php* in the template I used but still can't figure out what I have to change.

Answer (score 0):

you will find it on one of those palces

### Solution A: modules

if it's a module, you will find it here,
**change its Status to disable**

https://you-domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_modules&view=modules

### Solution B: installer manage

if it's a component, you will find it here,
**change its Status to disable**

https://you-domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=manage

### Solution C: plugins

if it's a plugin, you will find it here,
**change its Status to disable**

https://you-domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_plugins

### Solution Z: it's hardcoded to the template

locally search the while template Helix3 for the word **zend**
commit it or delete it.

notice that you can enable any of the modules/components/plugins if it's not the one needed
also, make sure to clear the cache
https://you-domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_config&view=application